# Can I use HDMI for audio only without video?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

When I connect an HDMI display to my computer, it uses it as a display. I can't figure out how to use the HDMI cable for audio only and only use my laptop monitor. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the HDMI display to be black, or do you just want your computer to stop stretching onto the second screen?

Comment: Just to stop stretching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to have your desktop confined to your computer's screen, go to System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement, and check Mirror Displays. That'll make it so that your HDMI display only acts as a mirror of the desktop you already have, rather than an extension of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to transmit only audio data via HDMI.

The [HDMI white paper (page 10)](http://www.hdmi.org/pdf/whitepaper/SilicaonImageHDMIWhitePaperv73(2).pdf) notes that the signal is sent in HDMI packets consisting of both audio and video. Despite all the pins, there are no separate audio and video signals, so there are also no HDMI A/V splitter cables.

The only way to get around this is to send blank video data (e.g. a black screen). I'm not sure exactly why you want only the audio, but here are my suggestions:

- If you're connecting it to an audio receiver, just send it along without worrying about the video.
- If you're connecting it to a TV, and don't want the TV to show your desktop, you can extend your desktop (turn off mirroring) and either have a blank desktop show up or put up any image you want on full screen while you do whatever you need to do on your MBP screen. That part's really up to you.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use an "HDMI Splitter 1 in 2 Out" device (not KVM) for this purpose.

reasoning:

- send audio to a receiver without fudging with a mirrored setup on the
  OS side
- avoid spdif because "Optical standards are limited to basically
  "LPCM" 2 channel only.. .ever.... period. The only way to transmit
  5.1 audio and it's LIMITED to 5.1 only, is via compressed bitstreamed DTS/DD" quote u/DHJudas