# Can I connect my HDMI amplifier as audio only?

Tags: macos, display, hdmi

I have a Denon AVR that I use to drive a set of speakers.  It's connected via HDMI to my MBP and everything works well.

However the amp also presents itself to the MBP as a video device and so when connected I get another display.  Since there's no monitor connected to the amp I want to disable this additional monitor (the cursor sometimes finds its way there, for example).

I want the audio device to remain.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

The answer in [Can I use HDMI for audio only without video?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162590/can-i-use-hdmi-for-audio-only-without-video) is not applicable because I have an external monitor connected via TB (and so can't resort to mirroring).

I've tried both SwitchResX and Disable Monitor but when I disable any of my screens everything goes black (and remains so) until I unplug and reconnect the disabled screen, so it's hard to test.

I'm running Movave btw.

Comment: You need to extract the audio from the HDMI signal.  Have a look at this [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/395368/119271) though opposite - user wanted macOS to ignore the audio device and only use video.  The bottom line is if you hook up an HDMI device, macOS is going to think an AV device is attached - because it is.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging it doesn't seem possible to completely remove the additional display.

However a trick I was not aware of (see [Use multiple displays with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl7c7ebe08/mac)) is to both extend the desktop (I use both my MBP LCD and an external display), and mirror the amplifier "display" to one of the real displays.  When arranging displays hold the Option key and drag the unwanted display onto a real display.  I mirror it with my MBP LCD.  Although it alters the screen resolution of the LCD upon mirroring, you can just change it back to what it was before.

This way the cursor cannot find its way to the amp display, nor can any windows inadvertently open on it.